# Transforming Immutable.js List of Maps to a List of Lists and then using this as data for google charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization, immutable.js

I am trying to use the google charts library to plot some time series data which at the moment is some dummy data I pasted into a separate file from my app.

I have an Immutable `List` looking something like this :

```
let data = [{"Date":1452457976,"Value":246.712065},{"Date":1452457990,"Value":268.240542}]
```

I'm trying to convert this to a plain javascript array of arrays, each containing a `Date` object and a value as follows.

```
let row_data = data.map( (list_object) => {
    let temp_list = Immutable.List();
    temp_list = temp_list.push(new Date(list_object.get('Date')));
    temp_list = temp_list.push(list_object.get('Value');
    return temp_list;
});

export default row_data.toJS();
```

I'm using this exported value as the input for constructing the data-table for a google chart using the [react-google-charts](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts) library. The result is that the section of the page has empty content and with nothing rendered without and no errors logged.

```
import row_data from 'data';

let options = {...};

let rows = row_data;

let columns = [
    {
        'type': 'date',
        'name': 'Date'
    },
    {
        'type': 'number',
        'name': 'Latency'
    }
]

this.setState({
    'rows': rows,
    'columns': columns,
    'options': options
});
```

Digging into the stacktrace, it looks like the argument being passed as rows is not of the type array, even though logging the variable gives me the following : `Array[<length>]` .

I feel like the way I am doing the immutable transformations are very hacky as I just started using the library today. Please do let me know if there is a better way to approach this.

Comment: why do you use immutable at all?  the use of the phrase "immutable transformations" suggests some mis-understanding. if you just need a manipulation lib, use lodash....

Comment: Thing is, I wanted to try it out as I was panning on integrating this into redux. But lodash is the way I'm probably going to go if I don't solve this soon.

Comment: Try exporting simply row_data and moving the "toJS()" function to the import in the 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is the proper pattern to convert unix timestamps into a Javascript `Date` object.

```
let time_labels = data.map( (ts_obj) => {
    let d = new Date();
    d.setTime(ts_obj.get('Date') * 1000);
    return d;
});
```

This is because the `setTime` function uses milliseconds.